# rendering dramatically different sized objects in opengl

Tags: opengl, scale

I am making a game with opengl (c++) where the player begins in a solar system populated with planets approx. 500 'real' kilometers across, and can then land on one of them which will be detailed at approx. 2 polygons per meter.

My question is how can I achieve this variation in size *continuously* without having to use a loading screen?

Comment: You may be interested in [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/55731/which-is-the-best-lod-method-for-planet-rendering).

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how can I achieve this variation in size continuously without having to use a loading screen?

Load [geometry](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html#update)/[textures](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html#map) in a separate thread(s) using pointers from `glMapBuffer()` and hope `glUnmapBuffer()` doesn't stall your primary thread for too long.